# How do I handle platform specific code in a Delphi XE7 app meant for multiple platforms?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I want my project to compile to iOS and Android. What do I do with code that is meant for one platform and not the other? Is there some way to indicate to Delphi XE7 to ignore e.g. Android specific code (like invoking an intent) when compiling for iOS?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are predefined compiler directives for just this use:

```
{$IFDEF ANDROID}
// Android-specific code here
{$ENDIF}

{$IFDEF IOS}
// IOS specific code here
{$ENDIF}

{$IFDEF MACOS}
// OS X specific code here
{$ENDIF}
```

There is a list of all of the pre-defined compiler directives in the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Conditional_compilation_%28Delphi%29).

Comment: I have an issue with these. It looks like when I compile for iOS, both the IOS and the MACOS constants are defined.

Comment: @RegisSt-Gelais: No, they're not. Read the linked documentation. (And if there *were* an issue with these, I'm not sure what you think commenting on my answer here will do to change that - you'd need to contact EMBT to file a bug report if you can create a reproducible test case.)

Comment: Sorry to disagree but if you look in the DCCIOS32 column, when you compile for iOS they are both defined. I fixed my issue by cascading my IFDEFs

Comment: @Regis: But if you look at the DCCOSX column, they're **not** both defined, so there is an easy way to differentiate which platform you're compiling for, so I don't see your point.

Comment: I know. The issue I pointed out is when compiling for iOS. In that case they are both defined. And then as I said in my second post, I fixed my issue by cascading IFDEFs. If MACOS is defined I then do a  IFDEF IOS  (ios stuff) ELSE (macos stuff)

Comment: Precisely the same issue here as well in Delphi 10 Seattle. When compiling for iOS Simulator, conditionals `IOS` and `MACOS` are both defined.

Comment: @RegisSt-Gelais, instead of cascading IFDEF you can use `IF Defined(MACOS) and not Defined(IOS)`
This will save some lines